# Running the GUI on Windows 7 (x64) - Connected daemon is not compatible with GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows

I run the monero-wallet-gui.exe file on Win 7 x64. I am then told that the daemon is not running. I click the start daemon button and it crashes. Then I get the "Connected daemon is not compatible with GUI." error.

Comment: Please post your output from daemon log on settings page.